# Which programming language(s) does Windows Phone 7 (WP7) support?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, boo

As I recall, WP7 supports C# but does not support any of the .Net dynamic languages (Ruby or Python).  Are any other programming languages besides C# supported?  Could an app be developed using Boo?

Comment: Regarding VB, the official asnwer that I can now give as an MSFTie is "coming in a near future update".

Answer (score 11):

Officially, only C# is supported so far. Unofficially, any language that can compile to a *verifiable* managed assembly (the verifiability requirement applies to all dependencies, too!) is good - so you should be able to use e.g. C++/CLI, F#, Delphi Prism...

Comment: Actually, not really - you cannot use C++/CLI due to the dependency restrictions and targeted platforms.

Comment: C++/CLI does not have any dependencies if used in `/clr:safe` mode (but then, of course, you don't get the full C++ language, nor the runtime library). As well, it outputs pure IL in that mode. So it should work.

Comment: This is a comprehensive and accurate answer to the OP. Some links to known demonstrations ie vb, f#, etc wouldn't go astray. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/08/20/f-windows-phone-7-silverlight-templates-now-on-visual-studio-gallery.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0 and http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7VBnetAndFSharp

Answer (score 6):

Currently, officially supported is C#.
In the medium term (although no time frame officially announced) will be full support for VB.Net & F#.
In the longer term will be official support for dynamic languages (IronRuby & IronPython) - although expect a restriction in what you can do with these languages due to marketplace restrictions.

**Update:**
The CTP of the Visual Basic tools are now available from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a808a69d-6119-47b7-b858-262be5c49915

Answer (score 5):

F# is supported on the phone.  The templates are not baked into Visual Studio yet but are available from this blog entry by Don Syme

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/08/20/f-windows-phone-7-silverlight-templates-now-on-visual-studio-gallery.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 1):

If you can compile it down to a .NET CF assembly, you could probably hack it to work - there's nothing explicitly *stopping* other languages from being used.

Answer (score 1):

IronRuby
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960707.aspx

Comment: I think though, languages that require the DLR will not be "verifiable" until a later time.

Comment: IronRuby and DLR are horribly outdated, deprecated, unsigned, and incompatible with Windows Phone 7 Visual Studio Express 2012. :(