# windows mobile phone 7 - C# only?

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, windows-phone-7

I've heard that app development on the new windows phone 7 is C# only.  Is that true?  I haven't been able to verify that on my own.  Can you please provide a link to this?

If true, is there any rumors about allowing VB.Net to create apps as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which programming language(s) does Windows Phone 7 (WP7) support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655313/which-programming-languages-does-windows-phone-7-wp7-support)

Comment: Sort of but it didn't address the VB.net issue specifically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You **can** write apps in VB.NET. [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4e97ea70-e479-4c05-814f-639d71690e5d) is the package you need to install (Visual Basic for Windows Phone Developer Tools)

But XNA projects are currently not supported in VB.NET (Silverlight projects only)

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/09/23/visual-basic-comes-to-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: You can write XNA apps for Phone 7 now.

Comment: @jeffamaphone XNA projects in VB.NET?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I guess I skimmed over that modifier.

Answer (score 5):

No, Windows phone 7 is not C# only. Apparently it will also support [VB and F#](http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7VBnetAndFSharp).

[Microsoft Previews VB for Windows Phone 7](http://www.internetnews.com/dev-news/article.php/3905281/Microsoft-Previews-VB-for-Windows-Phone-7.htm)

Also, check out this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/6e154937-4b28-4873-aa5d-636b758da949).

> **I received feedback from the GPM for the Microsoft VS Languages team, who indicates:**
>
> "there will definitely be support for
>   writing VB apps for Windows Phone 7,
>   but we are still working on the
>   details and the timeline".

Answer (score 1):

No, VB is supported as well... Visual Basic® CTP for Windows was released last month...

[Microsoft® Visual Basic® CTP for Windows® Phone Developer Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a808a69d-6119-47b7-b858-262be5c49915&displaylang=en)

> This CTP enables Visual Basic
>   developers to create Windows Phone 7
>   applications with the final version of
>   the Windows Phone Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1):

For XNA development it is C# only. Howevver, if you are developing in Silverlight there are more options available:

VB support is in CTP at the moment. gGt it from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a808a69d-6119-47b7-b858-262be5c49915&displaylang=en

The F# templates can be accessed from the Visual Studio Gallery. More details from http://bloggemdano.blogspot.com/2010/08/f-windows-phone-7-silverlight-templates.html

Dynamic language support is also, apparently, coming in the future as well. No details available yet though.

Answer (score 0):

The first supported release of Visual Basic for Windows Phone 7 now available for download from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4e97ea70-e479-4c05-814f-639d71690e5d&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

I remember some one mentioned about Delphi Prism too and some on Mono for Windows Phone 7