# What is a verifiable type in C#?

Tags: c#, types, field, clr, unions

What is a verifiable type in C#?

I am reading the **CLR via C#** book. And I come across the following piece of knowledge data:

> It should be noted that it is illegal to define a type in which a reference type and a value type
>   overlap. It is possible to define a type in which multiple reference types overlap at the same
>   starting offset; however, this is unverifiable. It is legal to define a type in which multiple value
>   types overlap; however, all of the overlapping bytes must be accessible via public fields for the
>   type to be verifiable.

The piece is related to the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute` attribute and the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute` attribute. It is about the  **Layout of a Type’s Fields**.

I can not find on the internet the definition of a verifiable type, are there any?

**UPDATE**

In the comments section below the following question was pointed out: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533471/what-is-verifiable-managed-assembly).

So, according to the answer I assume that a type is verifiable if any manipulations with the fields and the methods of the type do not break the CLR functionality. It is a roughly speaking definition, but is it correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this (see the answer not the question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533471/what-is-verifiable-managed-assembly

Comment: @RossGurbutt, thank you. I will update my question.

Comment: @RossGurbutt, should I remove my question from your pov? Or do you think that it is possible to get a useful info from an answer if it will be provided?

Comment: I'd leave it here in case anyone else needs the information. If someone with the ability to mark it as a duplicate thinks that's correct / wants to then they can.

Comment: @RossGurbutt, great. Thank you.

Comment: Also, it's not to do with breaking CLR functionality so much as just the possibility to execute unsafe code.