# Can I use C++ with Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c++, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm going to write an application for iOS, Mac OS X and Windows Phone 7.

To minimize the amount of work, I'd like to write the model only once, in C++ (otherwise I'd have to do it twice; in Objective-C and in C#).

Can I use C++ in a Windows Phone 7 application, together with C#?

Comment: A few websearches reveal that people have had some success with C++/CLI

Comment: @David Where? Where? My Google-fu wasn't strong enough? The other SO links I have found are both negative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539876/is-it-possible-to-program-for-windows-phone-7-in-standard-c-only and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455372/windows-phone-7-and-c-cli The only possibility is if you are an OEM or Microsoft :-)

Comment: @xanatos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655313/which-programming-languages-does-windows-phone-7-wp7-support

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539876/is-it-possible-to-program-for-windows-phone-7-in-standard-c-only/4540330#4540330

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from here: [Windows Mobile 7 and C++](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsmobiledev/thread/1f425c1b-b72a-4203-b594-6672b21ec695)

> All Windows Mobile 7 (now called Windows Phone 7 ) development, at
>   least initially, will be in managed code. Development using native
>   languages like C/C++ is not supported for third parties. You can
>   develop apps and games for Windows Phone 7 using the Silverlight or
>   XNA framework, and the initial release supports only C#, VB support is
>   supposed to be coming out soon.

It's from June 2010.

Answer (score 5):

No you cannot use C++ for WP7 apps. However you might be able to use [Monotouch](http://ios.xamarin.com/) to write some shared code in C# between the 2 platforms.

Comment: Agreed. If the application hasn't started development, you're better off going the other way and using Monotouch to share code.